# Flutter: How to get notified on url redirection and prevent redirections using WebView object:

Tags: redirect, flutter, webview

I'm using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) library which as I understand is the recommended library for `WebView` in flutter based on the fact that this is the library that is used by Google in their video tutorials such as this one: [Using WebViews in Flutter - Flutter In Focus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA-vLF_vnng).

Now I'm trying to understand how to accomplish 2 tasks using this library:

1. How to get notified on url redirections in WebView?
2. How to prevent url redirections in WebView?

During my research to found answers to those questions I see that people recommend using another library
for showing WebView and getting url redirections notifications, but those libraries have other problems (for example: shown AlertDialog will appear beneath the WebView and not above it) and I always will prefer to use the lib that is recommended by the creators of the platform (Google in this case).

**The Questions is:** Did anyone accomplished those tasks using this library or have a code sample to illustrate how it's done using this library?

Comment: I don't know about notifications but i think you can disable redirections by setting the property javascriptMode of the WebView to JavascriptMode.disabled

Comment: @RodrigoBastos disabling JavaScriptMode does not prevent redirection unfortunately.